# using the SFRestAPI singleton is there a way to request the results of a report?

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Is there an easy way to request the results of a report yet through the RestAPI using the Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS? (something similar to below?)

```
 SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:stringFilteredRESTRequest];
```